# Xlib drawing pixels fast and effectively

Tags: c++, drawing, rendering, pixel, xlib

I want to draw pixels using Xlib, I tried to optimize my code but XDrawPoint() takes a lot of time to do. For 120.000 pixels (300 x 400 window) it takes about one second to draw.

```
void sp::renderer::draw(pixel& drawablePixel)
{
     m_grahpics_values.foreground = drawablePixel.getColor().getHexRGB();
     XChangeGC(ptr_display, m_graphic_context, GCForeground, &m_grahpics_values);

     XDrawPoint(ptr_display, m_pixelMap, m_graphic_context, drawablePixel.getPosition().x, drawablePixel.getPosition().y);
}
```

And then I display it using XcopyArea()

```
void sp::renderer::display()
{
    XGCValues gr_values;
    GC gr_context;
    XChangeGC(ptr_display, m_graphic_context, 0, &gr_values); 

    if(m_showFps)
    {
        displayFps();   
        XCopyArea(ptr_display, m_pixelMap, *ptr_window, gr_context, 0, 0, m_renderSpaceWiddth, m_renderSpaceHeight, 0, 0);
        calculateFps();
    }
    else
    {
        XCopyArea(ptr_display, m_pixelMap, *ptr_window, m_graphic_context, 0, 0, m_renderSpaceWiddth, m_renderSpaceHeight, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

What can I do to run it quicker?

Comment: I think you are looking for XPutImage to draw a lot of pixels at once.

Comment: Thank you, it is so much faster now.